# How to get AIC from lm_robust object

Tags: r, regression, lm

How do I get an `AIC` from an `lm_robust` object (package `estimatr`)? I'm using `lm_robust` because I want to use a robust estimator for calculating the `SE`. Unlike the `lm` function, `AIC` is not provided when you run the summary function and running the `AIC` function on a `lm_robust` object produces an error. Below is a toy example of the kind of model I'm trying to run.

```
library(estimatr)

fake_data<-data.frame(outcome=rnorm(100,3.65,1),
                      pred1=rnorm(100,15,7),
                      pred2=as.factor(sample(1:5, 100, replace = T)))

mod1<-lm_robust(outcome~pred1+pred2,data=fake_data)
AIC(mod1)
```

here is what the error message looks like:

```
> AIC(mod1)
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "lm_robust"
```

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced that robust regression even *has* a clearly defined log-likelihood (i.e., a number that can be used as-is in computing likelihood ratio tests, AIC values, etc etc etc) ... ??? The solutions below give numbers, but I'm worried that they might not be meaningful numbers. e.g. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180451/aic-or-bic-for-robust-regression (unanswered)

Comment: @BenBolker Actually, I agree with you even if I gave the answer :). Because, *AIC* and *BIC* criterias are used in time series analysis mostly. I haven't seen any person who is interested in AIC in `lm`.(Please correct me if I am wrong and if there exists some to use AIC in academic world). Bottom line,If the problem is the calculation method, below is true. However, if the issue is the necessity of AIC in `lm_robust`...I am not really sure.

Comment: Plenty of people in ecology and evolution (my research field) use AIC for linear models (although probably slightly more often for GLMs)

Comment: @BenBolker Wow...I learned something. Thank you. Actually, I mostly used AIC for selecting the lag order etc in time series to decide the better fitted model . When it comes to making comparision between the linear models, as it is very common, I have been thought to have a look at the R-square instead. So what makes the AIC necessary for linear models instead of considering  the R-square?

Comment: AIC will be very similar to *adjusted* R2, or to Mallows' Cp statistic, i.e. it accounts for model compexity. [This CV answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197112/why-information-criterion-not-adjusted-r2-are-used-to-select-appropriate-la) suggests that AIC has better model selection properties ... "The penalty in 2 is enough to make 2 an unbiased estimator of the population 2 when none of the regressors actually belongs to the model ... however, 2 is not an optimal model selector."

Comment: @BenBolker But this is a time series example. (not a cross-section data as above). Anyway, I got the point and will be make some digging about it. Thanks!

Comment: @BenBolker I'm interested in using a statistic like AIC or BIC for model selection. Do you have suggestions for statistics that I could use for a robust regression of cross-sectional data?

Comment: Don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to do it with `lm_robust`, you may choose to calculate it by yourself as below,

The formula of `AIC`,

```
AIC = 2*k + n [Ln( 2(pi) RSS/n ) + 1]

# n : Number of observation
# k : All variables including all distinct factors and constant
# RSS : Residual Sum of Square
```

If we apply it to `R` for your case,

```
# Note that, I take k=7 since you have, 5 factors + 1 continuous and 1 constant

AIC_calculated <- 2*7 + 100* (log( 2*pi* (1-mod1$r.squared)*mod1$tss/100 ) + 1)


[1] 332.2865
```

which is same with both `lm` and `glm` outputs.

```
mod2<-lm(outcome~pred1+pred2,data=fake_data)

> AIC(mod2)
[1] 332.2865
```

And finally, of course, you can put this calculation into a function to call whenever you want by just giving `lm_robust` model inside it without having to set the `N` and `k` parameters for any given data like,

```
myAIC <- function(data) {

    2*(data$k+1) + data$N * (log(2*pi* (1-data$r.squared)*data$tss/data$N ) + 1)

}

> myAIC(mod1)
[1] 332.2865
```

**Note:** Results may be shown different in your computer because of the seeding differences when running the `sample()` function in dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround

```
mod1 = lm_robust(outcome ~ pred1 + pred2, data = fake_data)

#Create any fitted model using 'lm' as a placeholder
mod2 = with(list(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10)), lm(y ~ x))

#Copy values in `mod2` from `mod1`
mod2[names(mod2)] = mod1[names(mod2)]

#Calculate residuals in `mod2`
mod2$residuals = mod2$fitted.values - fake_data$outcome

AIC(mod2)
#[1] 326.6092
```

Comment: But is there a way to get AIC for lm_robust? For this analysis I want to use a robust standard error estimator, so that's why I'm using lm_robust